# Can not import groovy class in settings.gradle for java project in IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy

I created a spring boot project which uses gradle.
The project has a settings.gradle file, and i used groovy class in this file but can not be imported.
The code is used to include sub modules.

```
import groovy.io.FileType  // can not be imported
import java.nio.file.Paths

rootProject.name = 'godlenfire'
String rootPath = rootProject.projectDir.path

['app'].forEach {
    File dir = Paths.get(rootPath, it).toFile()
    dir.traverse([maxDepth: 3, nameFilter: 'build.gradle', type: FileType.FILES]) {
        def module = relativePath(it.parent).replace File.separator, Project.PATH_SEPARATOR
        include module
        logger.lifecycle("include ${module}")
    }
}
```

Thanks.

[image]

I excepted to import groovy class in .gradle file successfully.

---

Here is the gradle-wrapper.properties

[gradle-wrapper.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOORA.png)

Comment: Does it work when run in the CLI? E.g. if you run `gradle clean` within the terminal what is the result?

Comment: Hi @DmitryKhamitov , gradle clean failed due to the FileType.FILES in the settings.gradle file

Comment: what's the error? Which version of Gradle are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue by playing with `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Use Gradle from` option in IntelliJ. The idea is that this value should point to the valid Gradle binaries.

In my example below I'm using Gradle wrapper which means that Gradle will always be downloaded if it's missing.

[image: point to a valid directory with Gradle binaries]

However, when I reproduce the issue I'm just using the "Specified location" option that points to a random directory without Gradle binaries which causes my IntelliJ to "break".
[image: point to a directory without Gradle binaries]

[image: import is broken]

So, make sure that option is configured properly in your IntelliJ. You can also make sure that you are able to run `gradle` commands within the terminal as I mentioned in my comment to the question (if you are using Gradle wrapper you should likely run `./gradlew` commands).

Comment: I am using gradle from the gradle-wrapper.properties in idea,  but still can not import the groovy class

Comment: even changed to specific gradle in local, the groovy class is still red

Comment: @Felix do you have gradle-wrapper.properies in your project? Can you share its content please? Can you also share the layout of gradle folder inside the project? Is the distributionUrl (in gradle-wrapper.properties) available from your machine? If it's not then Gradle is essentially missing in your setup.

Comment: Has uploaded the image of gradle-wrapper.properties.
I tried your solution that using local gradle, i can gradle clean & reload all gradle project now, but the groovy class in settings.gralde, is still with red color in IDEA.

Comment: @Felix now try changing your distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties to contain `-all.zip` instead of `-bin.zip` and make sure the `Use Gradle from` is pointing to "gradle-wrapper.properties file". After that and clicking "Reload Gradle" (if not done automatically) in the status bar of your IDE you should see that Gradle is downloaded and the project will re-sync. Hopefully, the import error will be gone. Once all of that is done you can revert to using -bin.zip but I would always prefer -all.zip to have access to the source code of Gradle if needed.

Comment: Still has red color for import FileType groovy class. Thanks for your answer.

I may choose to use `import groovy.io.*`, although it is grayed in IDEA.